# Killing form of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, lie-algebras

It is well know that the Killing form $K(A, B) = 2nTr(AB)$ if $A, B \in \mathfrak{sl}_n(F)$ where $F$ is a field.

Now, let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$.

Do we have the Killing form $K(A, B):=Tr(adA.adB) = 2nTr(AB)$ for $A, B \in \mathfrak{sl}_n(R)$? as in the field case.

Comment: It's easier to calculate the Killing form for $\mathfrak{gl}_n(R)$. Then the Killing form for the subalgebra is just the restriction, because it's an ideal. (You can check that the trace is well defined because all the $R$-modules involved are free, finite rank). As for the gl case, by bilinearity, it's enough to check on some base, and there it's like the case over a field,.